# Additional step during sign-up with Auth0

Tags: auth0

How can I modify the Auth0 sign-up process so that the site owner has to approve new users?

The sign-up process by default sends an email to the new user asking for verification of their email account. Optionally, it sends an email to the user after they click a link in the verification email welcoming them to the application.

My customer requested that this process be modified to let them (the customer) *approve* new users' sign-up requests. The envisioned workflow is that the sign-up process (also) sends an email to the customer when a new user signs up and then the customer can somehow modify the user account to give them access to the application.

I don't know much about Auth0. From their documentation, I pieced together the following approach:

1. Add a rule that sends an email to the customer upon a user's first login (e.g. using one of the `Send email` template rules).
2. The email contains a some javascript or a link to a page where the customer can accept or reject the user. Accepting is done by adding a property to the user's profile using Auth0's [management API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/patch_users_by_id).
3. Add another rule that checks whether the user's profile contains the 
   property.

Does the above approach make sense or am I making this more complicated than necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this exact question was already answered on the Auth0 support forum, see [here](https://ask.auth0.com/forum/t/how-to-add-new-user-approver-workflow/1144). Even better, the answer is pretty much identical to the approach I proposed.

---

It seems Auth0 changed their support form structure. Here is a [new question](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-prevent-logging-in-until-admin-approval/9340/2) asking a very similar question. The solution is still pretty much what I initially proposed.

Comment: you didn't actually link to the article, just a generic link to their site.

Comment: @wordpress_designer Auth0 apparently restructured their support forum, breaking my link. I added a reference to a very similar question, but the solution is still pretty much the same.